# Can't find an already created Azure-SSIS Integration runtime in linked service configuration (Azure Data Factory)

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

Azure Admin has prepared an SSIS IR that can access a firewall protected Azure SQL Database. I'm trying to configure that linked service using this designated IR but not finding the IR in the "Connect via integration runtime" drop down menu :

[image]

Available IRs :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the linked service `connect via` property, you can only use the Azure integration runtime or self-hosted integration runtime. There is no option to select Azure-SSIS IR in the linked service

Azure SSIS integration is to create an SSISDB instance in your selected database server and deploy packages here. You can schedule to run these packages from the Azure data factory.

[image]

Refer to links [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure) & [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzDHB6LDL6k) for more information on Azure-SSIS Integration runtime.